# Kindly help me resolve my vba code error in excel userform am creating

Tags: excel, vba

a writing a vba user form in excel but i receive this error message when i run my application
and in the code section this is highlighted when i click on debug

`.RowSource = "Product Master!A2:D" & lr`

the error message reads

( could not set the RowSource properly. Invalid property value

Comment: Where is the rest of your code? We need to see the context too.

Comment: Probably needs `'`: `"'Product Master'!A2:D" & lr`.